# Inserting data from mysql from CSV using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fgetcsv

I have list of data in CSV and need to insert this data into a MySQL database. These data should be safely inserted i.e sanitation. So, I have used PDO object to rectify SQL injection. But, it fails to get data from CSV file and inserts null values.

Here is the example,

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=contact_list",$username,$password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "connection successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "connection Failed:" . $e -> getMessage();
}

// Create  CSV to Array function
function csvToArray($filename = '', $delimiter = ',')
{
    if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {
        return false;
    }

    $header = NULL;
    $result = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            if (!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $result[] = array_combine($header, $row);

        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    return $result;
}

// Insert data into database   

$all_data = csvToArray('contact.csv');
foreach ($all_data as $data) {

    $data = array_map(function($row){
        return filter_var($row, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        }, $data);

    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contact 
                (title, first_name,last_name,company_name,date_of_birth,notes) 
        VALUES (:t, :fname, :lname,:cname,:dob,:note)");

    $sql->bindParam(':t', $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(':fname', $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(':lname', $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(':cname', $data[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(':dob', $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(':note', $data[15], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    print_r($data);
    $sql->execute();    
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Can we see some example rows of contact.csv are the lengths of lines all < 1000?

Comment: what does `print_r($all_data);` return?

Comment: Enable error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and tell us what shows.

Comment: You can also import CSV directly into MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi I have tried to print the data to see whether it loops.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it dint show any errors.

Comment: @JonStirling I have changed the parameter to because i don't want to give value limitation.

Comment: @JonStirling Linked my sample in question.

Comment: Could it be as simple as having missing Titles in the Title column?

Comment: And also missing Company names in the company name column !!!!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes anyway it should save in db with null values if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the documentation for `array_combine()` you'll see that its purpose is to build an associative array. You use this function in `csvToArray()` but later in your code you are trying to get data using numeric keys. I wouldn't expect you'd ever have anything inserted.

On a side note, you are completely defeating the purpose of prepared statements by repeatedly preparing the same statement over and over again. Prepare once and execute many times. Individually binding parameters is rarely needed, in almost all cases you can provide the data to `PDOStatement::execute()` as an array. It's also bad form to store HTML entities in a database; if you need to output to HTML, you perform escaping at that point.

Something like this should work (adjust array key names as necessary.)

```
$all_data = csvToArray('contact.csv');
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contact 
    (title, first_name, last_name, company_name, date_of_birth, notes) 
    VALUES (:t, :fname, :lname,:cname,:dob,:note)");
foreach ($all_data as $data) {
    $params = [
        ":t"     => $data["t"],
        ":fname" => $data["fname"],
        ":lname" => $data["lname"],
        ":dob"   => $data["dob"],
        ":note"  => $data["note"],
    ];
    $sql->execute($params);
}
```

Comment: I tried this method by changing array index value like $data[0],$data[1].... but still it stores null values.

Comment: Did you read the first paragraph of my answer? Where I said your entire problem was the use of numeric indices?